# Make previous versions of an app inactive

Tags: android

I have made an android app, which is currently in the Alpha Track on Play Store. I didn't add a force update functionality till the version 2.2.0, so all the versions before that are still active. I want to either deactivate them or make the user update to the latest version since there are important updates in the latest version.

Comment: Rollout your new app to production, users will automatically get notified by play store app, and in future use https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates

Comment: I can't move the app to production track, that is the requirement of the company

Comment: It is upto the user if they want to update or not, if they have auto update on in playstore it will automatically get updated, you can't force it.